# Can not boot! initramfs error!

Tags: boot-failure, initramfs, busybox

I've had Ubuntu for a while and it'd been working fine till now. Every time I try to boot I get this message and I can not go any further:

```
BusyBox v1.17.1 (Ubuntu 1:1.17.1-10ubuntu1) built-in shell (ash)
Enter 'help' for a list of built-in commands

(initramfs)
```

My main worry are my files and pictures as I don't have a back-up.

Any advice would be very much appreciated!

Comment: You can always recover your files using a live cd or a live usb during boot. You can then mount your hard drive and find your folder (should be in the `home` folder). About the problem, do you remember what was the last thing you have done? Did you install a package from PPA repositories?

Comment: Press ctrl+D to boot from there

Comment: Check out this http://askubuntu.com/questions/137655/boot-up-fails-drops-to-initramfs-prompt-12-04

Comment: have you dual boot system ?

Answer (score 3):

I have the same problem...I did some commands in the terminal after logging into the live cd

**The following step is for removing the i-node**

In the terminal I typed

```
sudo debugfs -w /dev/sda1
debugfs 1.41.11 (14-Mar-2010)
debugfs: clri <8>
debugfs: quit
```

After that restart the system and again boot into  the live cd

In the terminal type

```
sudo fsck -yv /dev/sda1
```

It will work.....definitely

**After logging into the desktop in the terminal type the following commands**

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get autoclean
sudo apt-get check
```

For More Details visit the tutorial page

http://dcageek.blogspot.com/2013/02/ubuntu-initramfs-error-during-boot.html

For More Visit details

http://dcageek.blogspot.com

Answer (score 0):

If you boot off a live cd you can retrieve your files from your hard drive.

At the command-line try:

```
sudo dpkg-reconfigure -a
```

Answer (score 0):

Normally there are some lines just before the line posted on the question. If the problem is about mounting failure then [this](https://askubuntu.com/questions/137655/boot-drops-to-a-initramfs-prompts-busybox/148820#148820) may help. I had bad superblock problem on my /dev/sda3 and I fixed it by booting another Ubuntu located in another hard drive within the same box using the fsck command described in the link. You may have to wait for a running text on the screen. Let it finishes its job and your system will get back to work without losing any bit of your data.