# After install Ubuntu 14.04 not starting

Tags: system-installation, initramfs

First I installed windows 7 about 6 months, then I installed Linux Mint 16 yesterday, and today I installed Ubuntu 14.04.

I tarted it from a USB key, after the installation the PC restarted, I clicked on Ubuntu but it failed.

Please see the picture below:

[image: image captured]

What can I do?

Answer (score 0):

It seems like you may run into a recognised problem - [see this answer](https://askubuntu.com/questions/137655/boot-drops-to-a-initramfs-prompts-busybox) which explains how to progress when stuck at the initrafms prompt.