# Ubuntu 16.04 Installation goes straight to initramfs

Tags: initramfs

I am currently trying to install ubuntu on my xps 13. I have disabled secure boot and changed the sata mode to ahci.

I have the USB stick in and when I select "install ubuntu" or "try ubuntu" option, it goes straight to a screen with initramfs.

What seems to be the problem here? Any help is appreciated.

Comment: That's just part of the startup process. I'm assuming though, that it never progresses past this point. May I ask what kind of hardware is on that computer? Any discrete type graphics? Have you tried a different USB stick? How'd you make this USB stick?

Comment: it goes straight waiting for commands and i have to reboot using the reboot command. I have tried using different usb and I created it using rufus by following the instructions from the ubuntu site.

Comment: Have you seen this https://askubuntu.com/questions/528646/live-usb-boot-stuck-at-initramfs-prompt ? I know I keep harping on the USB thing, but I do think you should try a couple approaches. I remember that especially back in the day I would spend a lot of time pulling my hair out and find out that issues was something simple like that.

Comment: I checked my efi partition and it is mostly empty. I'll keep trying with different USBs I guess.