# Ubuntu BusyBox initramfs Error 14.04

Tags: boot, 14.04, grub2, initramfs, busybox

Suddenly after shutting down Ubuntu and when reopenning, I get prompted to one shell of BusyBox. I only had a set of options in *help* there.

[image]

I tried to follow this solution: [Boot drops to a (initramfs) prompts/busybox](https://askubuntu.com/questions/137655/boot-drops-to-a-initramfs-prompts-busybox)

I got a USB pen-drive and it has ISO of Ubuntu. I have selected "Try Ubuntu".

However, my Ubuntu is installed in an external hard disk (connected to the laptop via another USB port, other than the USB Pen drive), and I have Windows 8 installed by default in my laptop (in the internal hard disk). So when I am running the following command.

```
ubuntu@ubuntu:~$ sudo parted -l
Model: ATA ST1000LM024 HN-M (scsi)
Disk /dev/sda: 1000GB
Sector size (logical/physical): 512B/4096B
Partition Table: gpt

Number  Start   End     Size    File system  Name                          Flags
 1      1049kB  525MB   524MB   fat32        EFI system partition          boot
 2      525MB   567MB   41.9MB  fat32        Basic data partition          hidden
 3      567MB   701MB   134MB                Microsoft reserved partition  msftres
 4      701MB   2849MB  2147MB  ntfs         Basic data partition          hidden, diag
 5      2849MB  991GB   989GB   ntfs         Basic data partition          msftdata
 6      991GB   1000GB  8853MB  ntfs         Microsoft recovery partition  hidden, diag


Model: SanDisk Cruzer (scsi)
Disk /dev/sdb: 64.0GB
Sector size (logical/physical): 512B/512B
Partition Table: msdos

Number  Start   End     Size    Type     File system  Flags
 1      16.4kB  64.0GB  64.0GB  primary  fat32        boot, lba
```

None of this is actually my external hard disk in which my Ubuntu 14.04 is installed.

How can I solve this?

Comment: So your external disk is not even detected?

Comment: Yeah. That's what I am feeling that it's not detected when I am running the "Try Ubuntu" but I can boot from the external hard disk.

Answer (score 0):

Just remove the ext2fsd 0.68 from windows. and fix the Ubuntu by any of the method you like on this page ( I go with `fsck /dev/sdaX`, where "**X**" is your partition where is Linux install)

and the problem will solved.