# Digitalocean droplet boot drops to a (initramfs) prompts/busybox

Tags: server, busybox

I have digitalocean droplet ( a server). I restarted the droplet. Then Boot drops to a (initramfs) prompts/busybox. I found a solution:

[Ubuntu 15.10 - "BusyBox built-in shell (initramfs)" on every boot](https://askubuntu.com/questions/741109/ubuntu-15-10-busybox-built-in-shell-initramfs-on-every-boot)

But fsck command not available. Available Commands are:

[image: Available Commands]

The error is:

[image: Error]

What can I do about that?

Comment: I highly recommend that you read the duplicate answer that you found again. The available command you want is `exit`

Comment: @ElderGeek I don't see how that answers the question. OP ran `exit` (see screencap) but the error isn't saying the partition is damaged, it's saying the partition doesn't exist. (Though I don't have much experience with this sort of thing.)

Comment: @wjandrea I see that now. It's more clear to me since the edit 5 hours ago.

Comment: Either the root device has failed or there's a misidentification of the UUID in fstab..

Comment: I explained how I solved the problem.

Answer (score 1):

This issue is caused by the UUID in the /etc/fstab file not matching the UUID of the disk itself. DigitalOcean Support team have set my Droplet to boot to recovery mode. Then I power off and on the Droplet from the control panel. From the recovery mode, I mounted my droplets disk. I viewed the correct UUID with the command "blkid" and then edit the /mnt/etc/fstab file after mounting my disk to correct this. Then I power off and on the Droplet from the control panel once again. DigitalOcean Support team set the Droplet to boot normally. Then droplet worked very well.