# How to recover `ld-linux` file when i don't have any temporary copy of that

Tags: filesystem

I have deleted an important file named `ld-linux-x86-64.so.2` using `rm` command.
So I can't execute shell commands. and I only can execute builtin commands.

Now I don't know What is should do. please help.

through this [question](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/123353/bin-etc-lib64-root-sbin-deleted-or-moved-by-mv-folder-while-su/123358#123358) let me say you i have busybox.

Comment: Boot Ubuntu from a live USB, and copy the file from the live USB to the appropriate location in the installed Ubuntu.

Comment: Did you delete the symbolic link, or the file that it points to (something like `ld-2.xx.so`)? if the former, you *may* be able to fix it using busybox ln. Of course you'd need to be root, so it would likely involve setting init=/bin/busybox from the boot loader.

Comment: @steeldriver I deleted the file `/usr/lib64/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2`. is it the symbolic link or main file?

Comment: @ArchismanPanigrahi I can't because the softwares needed for are unavailable due the file deletion

Comment: Use someone else's computer to create the live USB. It is a good idea to create and safely store a live DVD of Ubuntu, for extreme cases like this,

Comment: Could try to use extundelete: https://askubuntu.com/a/317955/20054.

Comment: @mikewhatever i can't use `apt`

Comment: Well, obviously, you'll need another system, even something from USB or similar.

Comment: @PooiaFerdowsi it looks like you deleted the symlink. [Here](https://askubuntu.com/a/1029363/178692) is an answer that describes how to use `init=/bin/busybox sh` to get a statically-linked root shell (in that case, to fix a deleted libc.so.6). From there you should be able to use busybox's statically linked `ln` command to recreate the link. If you need futher help please [edit] your question to include your complete Ubuntu version information.

Answer (score 1):

**I encountered the same problem and finally managed to solve the problem without booting from USB or another. The machine is a Linux machine on AWS.**

Run the following command to recreate the symbolic link file `ld-linux-x86-64.so.2`

(You may need to change the version number `2.31`, you can autocomplete it by pressing tab)

```
/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/ld-2.31.so /bin/ln -s /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/ld-2.31.so /lib64/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2
```