# ubuntu 16.04 initramfs disk disappeared

Tags: boot, dual-boot, initramfs

I installed ubuntu 16.04 on a Dell Precision 5510 but after doing a software update when I rebooted the laptop it just went to a black screen that says something like

```
[    1.515367] nouveau 0000:01:00.0: priv: HUBO: 10ecc0 ffffffff (1c40822c)

BusyBox v1.22.1 (Ubuntu 1:1.22.0-15ubuntu1) built-in shell (ash)
Enter 'help' for a list of built-in commands

(initramfs)
```

And while there’s other questions about this, for some reason `sudo` doesn’t work for me, I get `/bin/sh: sudo: not found`. On top of that I can’t reinstall ubuntu because the USB installer says that “there is not enough space to install”. The gparted app doesn’t see any hard drive in the laptop, and boot-repair doesn’t give any repair options.

The answer to the question [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/781315/ubuntu16-04-boots-into-initramfs) doesn’t work; I get `fsck: error 2 (no such file or directory)`

I don’t know the name of the partitions but I’m pretty sure it’s not “sda” or whatever

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay, I managed to reinstall ubuntu successfully and I figured out how to avoid causing the same problem a second time around so I figured I’d post here. It has to do with `RAID/AHCI` and `cryptswap`.

Apparently the reason the disk disappeared was that something modified one of the disk settings in the BIOS, and I had to go back and change it from RAID to AHCI. That lets you do a fresh reinstall of ubuntu on your hard drive again.

The reason doing a routine software update causes this problem is because for some reason a `cryptswap1` thing was demanding a password to allow the updater to do stuff, and unless you have “Details” enabled in the software updates, the updater would skip some important stuff and you’d end up with a broken system. To do the update right you have to watch the “Details” tab and supply a password (can be any string you just have to type something) each time `cryptswap1` asks for a password. Then use one of the other answers on this website to get rid of `cryptswap1` for good.

Hope this helped