# Ubuntu Server turned into read-only then stopped working after restart

Tags: server, fsck, read-only

I am using ubuntu server at my home for my personal server. I use FTP, OwnCloud etc on that today morning suddenly noticed none of the sites, ftp are not working. on first time I could connect to SSH but couldn't create/delete any thing as it showing error message related being read-only. I see related posts but no where a fix was suggested except to contact hosting provider. I am hosting provider my self as this is a personal server. can any one suggest me a solution to this problem?

I tried restarting the server this time its not even connecting ssh so I manually opened server then I see some error messages as below -

**/dev/sda1:UNEXPECTED INCONSISTENCY; RUN fsck Manually**

**fsck exited with status code 4**

**Failure: File system check of the root filesystem failed.**

Now I am seeing a prompt as (initramfs) seems its now pointing to RAM file system (not sure if this is correct)

Please help me fix this issue.

Comment: Try the solution noted here http://askubuntu.com/questions/781315/ubuntu16-04-boots-into-initramfs