# "/dev/mapper/ubuntu--vg-root: clean xxx files, xxx blocks error

Tags: 16.04

this did not work https://askubuntu.com/a/830632/542960

I am stuck on `login loop`. it had `LVM` error too. but i fixed it.

with that

```
edit /etc/lvm/lvm.conf and change use_lvmetad=1 to use_lvmetad=0
execute update-initramfs -k *KERNEL_VERSION* -u ;
```

Now how can i fix?

when i go to etc fstab, i see that

> dev mapper ubuntu vg root ext 4 errors=remount-ro 0 1
>
> UUID fasdas-a2323-23232-232 /boot ext2 defaults 0 2
>
> UUId xxxxxxxxxxxxx /boot/efi vfat umask=0077 0 1
>
> /dev mapper ubuntu-vg-swap_1 none swap sw 0 0

I went to live cd. made sudo fsck dev mapper ubuntuvgroot and it showed same lines.

But when on ubuntu prelogin, it was saying

```
is mounted, can not fsck
```

like this.