# Ubuntu wont boot and shows busybox console

Tags: 14.04, boot, dual-boot, busybox

I use windows 10 and ubuntu 14.04.4 in dual boot.Recently whenever I try booting into ubuntu,it shows me this,

```
    ata1.00 SRST failed (errno-16)
    ata1.00 SRST failed (errno-16)
    ata1.00 SRST failed (errno-16)
    ata1.00 SRST failed (errno-16)
    ....giving up
```

then busybox console shows up.I tried fixing this following this, 
[Boot drops to a (initramfs) prompts/busybox](https://askubuntu.com/questions/137655/boot-drops-to-a-initramfs-prompts-busybox)

if fixed my problem for once but after I did my stuffs, shut the pc down and then came back again, the problem reappeared. This time, I cant detect my entire hard drive using live CD(ubuntu iso in a usb stick). But grub is still fine and I can boot into Windows 10.The only thing thats different now is that during BIOS messages,it takes about 20-30 seconds just to detect my harddrive which was faster before.Could that be the issue?

by the way,I use Diskinternals Linux Reader for copying files from my ext4 partition when I am on windows and I can still see that partition and can see my files as well.

Comment: I have the identical problem under Mint 18. The hard disk showed errors, so I ran fdisk /dev/sda1 -y from the BusyBox prompt. Long screed while fixing, then kernel panic. On reboot, I get exactly what you describe. I'm happy to reinstall the whole machine, but right now it can't find the ata1 disk which was /dev/sda1 before.