# My computer boots to Grub Rescue --> (initramfs)

Tags: grub2, initramfs

My computer is displaying a Grub issue. I tried the below listed commands:

```
set root=(hd0,msdos6)
set prefix=(hd0,msdos6)/boot/grub
insmod normal
normal
```

However the computer just boots into another shell.

```
(initramfs)
```

Is the partition totally lost or is there a chance of restoring it?

I don’t have an Ubuntu live CD.  However I do have a startup disk which ultimately I ended up installing it onto the 2nd drive that I initially installed (which caused this problem) (as a backup drive).

I’d ideally like to get the original installation back. I’ve resorted to removing the 2nd drive and battling with the grub rescue command prompt.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Boot drops to a (initramfs) prompts/busybox](http://askubuntu.com/questions/137655/boot-drops-to-a-initramfs-prompts-busybox)

Comment: can you run intel boot agent ?

Answer (score 0):

It sounds to me like you may have installed grub on the 2nd drive when you were installing your "backup". try booting from your 2nd drive and see if Grub comes up like it is supposed to.

There may have aslo been an error when you were installing grub. You can download a utility called Rescatux that will allow you to reinstall Grub. If my first recommendation doesnt work try installing grub with the Rescatux utility to your /dev/sda and then try booting into your installation.

Rescatux utility can be found here: http://www.supergrubdisk.org/rescatux/

Answer (score 0):

created a boot disk and booted with it.  However it was unable to find the boot partition on the original drive.  Having said that, if I connect the 2nd drive and boot off of that, I am able to mount the original drive and access some of the files.  My concern really was the hours of work customizing the actual settings and applications within the original (1st) drive.