# Ubuntu Login Fails, Opens Inittramfs Terminal

Tags: login, initramfs

I'm running Ubuntu 16.04 and the following happens:

1. Turn on computer
2. Able to login with sda3_crypt
3. I get an initramfs terminal

I do not know linux and have no idea what to do.

EDIT 1:

I do see the following sometimes in the initramfs console:

```
[    3.541417 sd 4:0:0:0:0: [sdb] Aksing for cache data failed
[    3.541487 sd 4:0:0:0:0: [sdb] Assuming drive cache:: write through
```

Please help! (the more dumbed-down, the better and much appreciated)

Comment: Usually there is an error message hinting in some direction on what is wrong. Please search for it and quote it in an edit of your question.

Comment: Thanks for the response. Unfortunately, there wasn't any error initially. After messing about for a while I finally got some kind of an error and have updated my initial thread with it

Comment: OK, this is actually not an error but a notice about the harddisk and its assumed cache mode.

Answer (score 0):

After a bit of a Hail Mary, I came across [Boot drops to a (initramfs) prompts/busybox](https://askubuntu.com/questions/137655/boot-drops-to-a-initramfs-prompts-busybox), specifically @ramsudharsan's answer wich is what was happening to me.  I used the following and am now able to log in again.

```
 fsck /dev/mapper/ubuntu--vg-root -y
```

then,

```
 reboot
```