# Booting to initramfs again and again

Tags: boot, 16.04, initramfs

Novadays it is very hard to study with an unstable computer.

I had my laptop for about 5 years and a year ago I installed Ubuntu alongside Windows (which I never used).
I had no problems for about a year, but two weeks ago my computer boot to initramfs.

Simple solutions like "just type 'fsck /dev/sda1' " didn't work so first time I reinstall Ubuntu (and deleted Windows). But after a few days the problem came back. So, I learned, how to fix problem with live CD (based on [the first answer of this question](https://askubuntu.com/questions/137655/boot-drops-to-a-initramfs-prompts-busybox)). But the problem appears again and again after about 3 days.

Today I couldn't boot Ubuntu.

So, my question is: "What can cause Ubuntu to boot in initramfs so often? How can I avoid surprises again?"

Comment: Could be a hardware problem with the HDD. Do check its status with the included Disk utility, aka Disks.

Comment: This happened to me today with an old partition containing Ubuntu 14.04. I cold booted at (initramfs) prompt and selected an older kernel version. Then I ran `sudo apt update` and `sudo apt upgrade` then I got newer kernel version 3.19.0-77 which seems to work fine.

Answer (score 0):

try booting into a live CD and running the command

```
fsck /dev/sdX
```

(X being the device with your root file system)
and post the output here.

Also, while booting up, during the boot animation that says Ubuntu, press ESC to view the verbose boot log and look for errors that have to do with volumes not being found, as it could be an error with fstab.
Also look for a command that takes a long time to complete, this signifies that you need to run an fsck.