# Boot drops to a (initramfs) prompts busybox

Tags: boot, initramfs

This question duplicated with [this](https://askubuntu.com/questions/137655/boot-drops-to-a-initramfs-prompts-busybox). I asked for answer this question. Because I cannot answer the original question because I don't have 10 reputations.

After hard reset I've encountered with:

```
BusyBox v1.18.5 (Ubuntu 1:1.18.5-1ubuntu4) built-in shell (ash)
Enter 'help' for a list of built-in commands.

(initramfs)
```

Comment: You do have more than 10 reputation points.

Comment: Yes you're right. However, 100 reputations have already come automatically because of I member of other stack sites. I guess, after 111 rep I can answer the questions :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Actually the solution is easy
just write the command of `fsck /dev/sdax` like the below and give `Y` if the console ask for fixing something:

```
(initramfs) fsck /dev/sda1
```

or

```
(initramfs) fsck /dev/sdaX
```

`X` specifies mounted disk part number.