# Ubuntu 18.04 to 20.04 upgrade failure - won't boot

Tags: boot, grub2, 20.04, do-release-upgrade

Last night I was trying to upgrade from ubuntu 18.04 to 20.04 using the do-release-upgrade command. During the upgrade, the system logged me out and told me to reboot. After the reboot, I was unable to launch my windows (Bitlocker recovery) or ubuntu partitions (initramfs terminal). After the GNU GRUB v2.02 menu, selecting recovery options didn't make a difference (still logged into initramfs).

I tried to check the partition with fsck but didn't see any partitions resembling my drive.
[initramfs-prompts-busybox](https://askubuntu.com/questions/860964/boot-drops-to-a-initramfs-prompts-busybox?noredirect=1&lq=1)

I was able to boot from a usb running xubuntu (only 1 out of 4 usbs worked for some reason) and got gparted to list my partitions:
[partitions list](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hLMZR.png)

After rebooting once again, I don't see the initramfs menu. Instead, I either got a black screen after selecting regular boot options or Recover Menu after selecting the recovery mode.

I tried boot-repair with a live usb
[grub-into-busybox](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1194328/grub-into-busybox) -
[boot-repair](http://ubuntuhandbook.org/index.php/2016/11/install-boot-repair-ppa-fix-boot-problems/) -
[boot-repair summary](http://pastebin.ubuntu.com/p/nrzXddBfRv/)

Issues persist as before (now the ubuntu text is smaller for some reason). After trying to boot ubuntu I see the manufacturer logo indefinitely (ASUS in search of incredible).

Booting in with nomodeset didn't seem to do anything (assuming I did it correctly).
[black-screen](https://askubuntu.com/questions/162075/my-computer-boots-to-a-black-screen-what-options-do-i-have-to-fix-it/162076#162076)

I've spent close to 6 hours on this now without much progress. Any advice on what to try next would be greatly appreciated.

**edit 1:**
from recovery mode -> root console

```
root@user$ fsck /dev/nvme0n1p6
root@user$ /dev/nvme0n1p6 is mounted e2fsck: Cannot continue aborting.
```

```
root@user$ fsck -nf /dev/nvme0n1p6

fsck from util-linux 2.34
e2fsck 1.45.5 (07-Jan-2020)
Warning! /dev/nvme0n1p6 is mounted.
Warning: skipping journal recovery because doing a read-only filesystem check.
Pass 1: Checking inodes, blocks, and sizes
Inode 1448636 extent tree (at level 1) could be shorter. Optimize? no
Pass 2: Checking directory structure
Pass 3: Checking directory connectivity
Pass 4: Checking reference counts
Pass 5: Checking group summary information
Free blocks count wrong (25787609, counted=12663609)
Fix? no

Free inodes count wrong (12663604, counted 12663609)
Fix? no

/dev/nvme0n1p6: 1254604/13918208 files (0.4% non-contiguous), 29857319/55644928 blocks
```

running fsck from live usb running xubuntu

```
$ sudo fsck /dev/nvme0n1p6
fsck from util-linux 2.31.1
e2fsck 1.44.1 (24-Mar-2018)
/dev/nvme0n1p6: clean, 1254602/13918208 files, 29857328/55644928 blocks
```

from grub terminal

```
grub> fsck
error: can't find command
```

```
grub> ls

(proc) (hd0) (hd0,gpt6) (hd0,gpt5) (hd0,gpt4) (hd0,gpt3) (hd0,gpt2) (hd0,gpt1)
```

-windows partition now works - found my BitLocker key in my Microsoft account.

-I'm running Intel integrated graphics

-ASUS ZenBook 14 UX433FA-DH74
-I didn't find /boot/grub.cfg, instead i found /boot/grub/grub.cfg which I edited to remove all instances of quiet splash. Results are the same I think (flashing underscore "_" in the top left corner of screen).

```
grub> ls (hd0,gtp6)/boot efi/ grub/ config-5.4.0.47-generic vmlinuz-5.4.0-47-generic memtest86+.bin memtest86+.elf memtest86+_multiboot.bin config-5.4.0-48-generic vmlinuz-5.4.0-48-generic vmlinuz.old initrd.img.old System.map-5.4.0-48-generic initrd.img-5.4.0-48 vmlinuz System.map-5.4.0-47 initrd.img initrd.img-5.4.0-47-generic
```

`sudo fsck -f /dev/nvme0n1p6`

```
fsck from util-linux 2.31.1
e2fsck 1.44.1 (24-Mar-2018)
Pass 1: Checking inodes, blocks, and sizes
Inode 1448636 extent tree (at level 1) could be shorter.  Fix<y>? yes

Pass 1E: Optimizing extent trees
Pass 2: Checking directory structure
Pass 3: Checking directory connectivity
Pass 4: Checking reference counts
Pass 5: Checking group summary information

/dev/nvme0n1p6: ***** FILE SYSTEM WAS MODIFIED *****
/dev/nvme0n1p6: 1254394/13918208 files (0.4% non-contiguous), 29892046/55644928 blocks
```

Updated the BIOS now ubuntu (including recovery mode) is dropping me back into initramfs. (bios update turned secure boot back on - turning it off prevents initramfs and goes to recovery instead)

from usb:

```
xubuntu@xubuntu:~$ sudo mkdir /mnt/ubu
xubuntu@xubuntu:~$ sudo mount /dev/nvme0n1p6 /mnt/ubu
xubuntu@xubuntu:~$ ls -al /mnt/ubu
total 128
drwxr-xr-x  26 root root  4096 Oct  2 15:13 .
drwxr-xr-x   1 root root    60 Oct  2 16:27 ..
drwxr-xr-x   2 root root  4096 Oct  1 02:01 bin
drwxr-xr-x   4 root root  4096 Oct  1 02:00 boot
drwxr-xr-x   2 root root  4096 Apr  3 21:03 cdrom
drwxr-xr-x   4 root root  4096 Feb  3  2020 dev
drwxr-xr-x 160 root root 12288 Oct  1 03:54 etc
drwxr-xr-x   3 root root  4096 Apr  3 21:04 home
lrwxrwxrwx   1 root root    32 Sep 25 10:22 initrd.img -> boot/initrd.img-5.4.0-48-generic
lrwxrwxrwx   1 root root    32 Sep 25 10:22 initrd.img.old -> boot/initrd.img-5.4.0-47-generic
drwxr-xr-x  22 root root  4096 Oct  1 01:29 lib
drwxr-xr-x   2 root root  4096 Oct  1 01:25 lib32
drwxr-xr-x   2 root root  4096 Oct  1 01:25 lib64
drwx------   2 root root 16384 Apr  3 21:02 lost+found
drwxr-xr-x   4 root root  4096 Apr  3 22:35 media
drwxr-xr-x   5 root root  4096 Jun 24 15:14 mnt
drwxr-xr-x   6 root root  4096 May 20 17:15 opt
drwxr-xr-x   2 root root  4096 Apr 24  2018 proc
drwxr-xr-x   2 root root  4096 Aug 10 21:42 recovery
drwx------  12 root root  4096 Oct  2 01:09 root
drwxr-xr-x  14 root root  4096 Apr  3 21:04 run
drwxr-xr-x   2 root root 12288 Oct  1 01:34 sbin
drwxr-xr-x  18 root root  4096 Sep 28 12:00 snap
drwxr-xr-x   2 root root  4096 Feb  3  2020 srv
drwxr-xr-x   2 root root  4096 Apr 24  2018 sys
drwxrwxrwt   7 root root  4096 Oct  2 16:13 tmp
drwxr-xr-x  13 root root  4096 Jul 31 04:29 usr
drwxr-xr-x  14 root root  4096 Feb  3  2020 var
lrwxrwxrwx   1 root root    29 Sep 25 10:22 vmlinuz -> boot/vmlinuz-5.4.0-48-generic
lrwxrwxrwx   1 root root    29 Sep 25 10:22 vmlinuz.old -> boot/vmlinuz-5.4.0-47-generic
```

I'm able to boot up a live ubuntu 20.04.1 usb. Should I try to re-install it? It says I will lose all my files and programs.

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/113661/discussion-on-question-by-amourav-ubuntu-18-04-to-20-04-upgrade-failure-wont).