# I shut off my PC and turned back on and serious errors won't let me back in

Tags: boot, startup

I have a major issue, I DO NOT have a CD to start off and this happened when my PC turned on.

```
No init found. Try passing  init= bootarg.
Busybox v1.21.1 (Ubuntu 1:1.21.0-iubuntu) built-in shell (ash) Enter 'help' for a list of built-in commands
(initramfs)
(initramfs)
Built-in commands:
. : [ alias break cd chdir command continue echo eval exec exit export false getopts hash help let local orinit pwd read readonly unset wait [ [[ ash awk basename blockdev  cat chmod chroot chvf egrep env expr false fbset fdflush fgrep find grep gunzip gzip hostname iconfig............etc

(initramfs) ubuntu
/bin/sh: ubuntu: not  found
(initramfs)
```

And I believe this came up when I pressed 'help'.

Comment: What were you fiddling with before this accident ?

Comment: Nothing, I had 4 browsers open and had to many tabs open and the pc got slow so I just pressed the power supply button and the PC shut off very fast, that is it

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Boot drops to a (initramfs) prompts/busybox](http://askubuntu.com/questions/137655/boot-drops-to-a-initramfs-prompts-busybox)

Comment: Ya but I need to know what to do

Comment: Please follow those steps in the link provided. Just boot into `initramfs` (as you computer will do so until error is corrected) then follow what was done on that link post. Follow the post by __ramsudharsan__.

Comment: I do not have a live CD for it as the solution for his asks and my code error is also not the same, and for a USB( I guess any USB as it says,  nothing happens when I put one in) I just need to know what codes to press and what commands to issue on the screen

Comment: You are not paying attention, look at one of the answers you don't need a live cd. And your problem is the same. I said you look at ramsudharsan's answer...

Comment: So basically go and enter command "exit", is that the one your talking about?

Comment: Yes its start with exit then `fsck` etc...

Comment: They didn't work. Maybe because similar looking but different corruption.When I pressed "EXIT" it just took me to a bunch of traces logs and at the bottom said end trace with a bunch of letter/number mix. And from there the keyboard is unresponsive and have to press the power button to start over.

Comment: Ideas? And same when you press help then exit, a little bit different layout but second half page trace logs and last trace log says kernel offset followed by a few intervals of code which I can decipher none of and after the bracket that says relocation range?????