# Stuck at BusyBox v1.22.1 (Ubuntu 1:1.22.0-19ubuntu2) built-in shell (ash)

Tags: boot, initramfs

I'm getting the below error. I have a dual boot Installed Windows 10 and Ubuntu 17.04 64-bit in Lenovo G500-I5-12GB RAM.

[image: black screen]

I also tried with `fsck /dev/sda7` iIt started checking, but after 5 checks only numbers were showing on the screen (Like Matrix).

Comment: Did you try the commands suggested in the error text ? `e2fsck -b 8193 /dev/sda7` or `e2fsck -b 32768 /dev/sda7` ? This will check your partition using an alternate super block.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [My computer boots to a black screen, what options do I have to fix it?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/162075/my-computer-boots-to-a-black-screen-what-options-do-i-have-to-fix-it)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Boot drops to a (initramfs) prompts/busybox](https://askubuntu.com/questions/137655/boot-drops-to-a-initramfs-prompts-busybox)