# Hdd issue after install Ubuntu

Tags: hard-drive

I  installed Ubuntu on a Dell laptop i3. After some issues i installed parted magic to check the hdd.

The hdd I a model ST1000LM035-1RK172

The laptop is:
Dell Inspiron 15 3567 - 15.6" - Core i3-u - 4GB RAM - 1 TB 
Processsor Skylake 
The hard disk is Seagate. ST1000LM035
I upload a picture

https://pasteboard.co/HiwbLPe.jpg

The bios:
I changed in the boot list option from uefi to legacy
Also I disabled the secure boot

In the advanced legacy option rom I checked the option “enable legacy option ROM”

I follow the steps you said me. 
I installed the Ubuntu 16.04 but in certain time the computer freeze (the screen of the application was black and night). 
Then I restart the Pc and spear message like kernel panic

I upload an image of the error mentioned. 
https://pasteboard.co/HiwgmWU.jpg
Then I entered the usb stick and open the “try Ubuntu “ and open a terminal. 
I enter the next. 
Sudo frisk -l
Appear 
/dev /sda1. Size 927.8 G type Linux
/dev/sda2 size 3.8 G type extended
/dev/sda5 size 3.8 G type Linux swap/Solaris

After this o entered I entered to the mode “try Ubuntu “ and open the “disk” app. 
I check the health of the hdd using the option “smart data and self tests”
See below what appear. It’s possible to infer something? Or it’s necessary to another tests?

https://pasteboard.co/HiwQbh2.jpg
After this I press the button “refresh” and appear error 
https://pasteboard.co/HiwS68h.jpg

I tried to format using the “disk” app inside the “try Ubuntu “
Appear error

https://pasteboard.co/HiBl7aY.jpg

Comment: Use pastebin then drop the link here!

Comment: 1) What does the initramfs message say? Isn’t it the well-known [fsck case](https://askubuntu.com/questions/137655/boot-drops-to-a-initramfs-prompts-busybox)? If it does not help: 2) Have you tried [Boot-Repair](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Boot-Repair)? If it cannot help automatically, it creates a log with some more useful info than what I can find in your current log.

Comment: Thanks. I newbie in this area. I will check your suggestions.thanks.