# Cannot reinstall Ubuntu 18.04

Tags: reinstall, preinstallation, reinstalling

I found this

ACPI Error : Method parse/execution failed.

BusyBox v. 27.2 (Ubuntu 1:1.27.2ubuntu3) built-in shell (ash)
Enter 'help' for a list of built-in commands.

(initramfs)

Comment: That's nice. How is what you found related to your title in any way? Did you have a question?

Comment: Trying to boot from USB but failed, Any command do I need to put for (initramfs)?

Comment: Did it ever boot properly? A link to the instructions you used would be helpful.

Comment: More details would help. How did you create the live USB? Perhaps *that* is the problem?

Comment: I create the live using startup disk, for the first and second time when trying install, got some problem with grub, for the third time stuck with that message.

Comment: During installation I had click back in when choose something which I don't remember and suddenly the quit shows up I click to it, boom this problem happen

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Boot drops to a (initramfs) prompts/busybox](https://askubuntu.com/questions/137655/boot-drops-to-a-initramfs-prompts-busybox)