# No boot device on dell laptop running ubuntu 14.04 after power loss

Tags: grub2, uefi, initramfs

RI had a no boot device black screen after switching my laptop back on after several weeks.
Following dell support instructions I went to the Bios menu (tapping the F2 key during the initial boot sequence). In the Bios menu, I switched the boot mode from Legacy to UEFI and restarted. I now have a initramfs prompt and after typing reboot, GRUB is displayed and if I choose the top Ubuntu option, I get a kubuntu screen followed by the initramfs prompt again.

`(initramfs) exit`
`ALERT! /dev/disk/by-uuid/e93ad2e1 does not exist. Dropping to a shell!`

`(initramfs) cat /proc/cmdline`
`BOOT_IMAGE=/boot/vmlinuz-3.19.0-80-generic.efi.signed root=UUID=e93ad2e1 ro quiet splash`

`(initramfs) cat /etc/fstab`
`cat: can’t open ‘/etc/fstab’: no such file or directory`

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Boot drops to a (initramfs) prompts/busybox](https://askubuntu.com/questions/137655/boot-drops-to-a-initramfs-prompts-busybox)

Comment: The link on the method of the possible duplicate is now obsolete

Comment: Did you run the `fsck` as directed in that link? `fsck /dev/sdX` insn't obsolete!

Comment: Yes, sorry. `fsck /dev/sdaX` `/bin/sh: fsck: not found `

Comment: Please note the `X` represents your partition number which I believe should be `1` so do `fsck /dev/sda1` and accept all requests with a `y` :-)

Comment: Ok but still getting a not found `fsck /dev/sda1 -y`

Comment: `cd /` `find . -name fsck*` `./sbin/fsck.btrfs`