# Ubuntu 18.04.1 not booting properly showing busybox

Tags: 18.04, busybox

! [Ubuntu 18.04 not booting properly 
      Showing  [3.244726  AMD -vi Unable to write to IOMMU perf counter 
3.365182.   Could not get size 0×80000000000000e
3. 367212 MODSIGN : couldn't get UFEI db list 
3. 6894l3 couldn't get size O×80000000000000e

Amd GPU ERROR
-boot args (cat/proc/cmdline)

Missing modules (cat/proc/modules: is/Dev)

ALERT ! UUID =30cad26-e3b8-bd9c-b6dd5932d6d6 does not exist. Dropping to a shell .

Busybox v 1.27.2   Ubuntu built in shell (ash) 
Enter help

(Initramfs)_ ]

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Boot drops to a (initramfs) prompts/busybox](https://askubuntu.com/questions/137655/boot-drops-to-a-initramfs-prompts-busybox)

Answer (score 0):

It look like the [UUID](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/UsingUUID) of the [root partition](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/DiskSpace#Root_partition_.28always_required.29) is wrong or hash changed for some reason. So you need to fix/update to the proper UUID.

This can be done by booting into a [Ubuntu Live-CD](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/LiveCD) and open a konsole and type in the following commands:

```
$ sudo blkid
/dev/sdb1: UUID="xxxxxxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxxxxxxxxxx" UUID_SUB="xxxxxxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxxxxxxxxxx" TYPE="btrfs" PARTUUID="xxxxxxxx-xx"
/dev/sda1: UUID="xxxxxxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxxxxxxxxxx" UUID_SUB="xxxxxxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxxxxxxxxxx" TYPE="btrfs" PARTUUID="xxxxxxxx-xx"
```

The output of the command might be a bit different according to your disk partion tabe. In most cases the `/dev/sda1` is the root filesystem. So you need to mount the partition in the running live system and change UUID in the [/etc/fstab](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Fstab) file

```
$ sudo mount /dev/sda1 /mnt
$ editor /mnt/etc/fstab

# /etc/fstab: static file system information.
#
# Use 'blkid' to print the universally unique identifier for a
# device; this may be used with UUID= as a more robust way to name devices
# that works even if disks are added and removed. See fstab(5).
#
# <file system>                           <mount point> <type>  <options> <dump>  <pass>
# / was on /dev/sda1 during installation
UUID=xxxxxxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxxxxxxxxxx /             btrfs   defaults  0       0
```

The filesytem type and might be differnt in your case. If `/dev/sda1` does not contain the `/etc/fstab`, then you have the wrong partition. `umount /mnt` and try the other partitions.