# Ubuntu booting stops after grub with initramfs error

Tags: boot, 64-bit, initramfs, uuid

My Ubuntu system is not booting and stops at initramfs error as shown in the snapshot below.

[image: Pic1]

I have tried to enter `exit` as suggested by @ramsudharsan in [Boot drops to a (initramfs) prompts/busybox](https://askubuntu.com/questions/137655/boot-drops-to-a-initramfs-prompts-busybox), but it is stuck at the same screen.

So any help'd be appreciated to find a fix to this problem.

**Attempts**

I tried the fix suggested by @Amith KK in [Boot drops to a (initramfs) prompts/busybox](https://askubuntu.com/questions/137655/boot-drops-to-a-initramfs-prompts-busybox) after booting ubuntu 14.04 64bit live usb, the same problem persists. I even tried using `bootrepair`, yet no change.

And at last I tried to copy the data to another external HDD to format my hard disk, now it seems my SATA hard disk is extremely slow, giving only below 1mbps speed(external hard disk is fine I checked it with another system).

**Note**

It did not certainly happen after any update as the system was not connected with internet

**System details**

Single boot Ubuntu 14.04 LTS 64bit, 2GB ram, SATA HDD

Comment: @Itra I have clearly mentioned where I am stuck with the fix suggested in that post. I hope its not a duplicate.

Comment: i don't see `fsck` in the image?

Comment: @ss1729 try to uninstall grub and again install install on true /dev/...

Comment: @GeorgeUdosen `sudo fsck -b 32768 /dev/sda2 -y` is the last command in the pic. pls check

Comment: The command can't run as the file system is mounted! it should have been the first thing to run after the error!

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to fix "The system is running in low-graphics mode" error?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/141606/how-to-fix-the-system-is-running-in-low-graphics-mode-error)

Comment: @GeorgeUdosen and it is not even going into the console mode now ?. dont know how the fixes suggested in that post helps me if thats not possible

Comment: @GeorgeUdosen Please check. I have edited OP. hope I have well explained why its not a duplicate.