# How to fix the ubuntu file system /dev/sda error?

Tags: 16.04, fsck

I encountered this error on my Ubuntu machine:

```
The root filesystem on /dev/sda1 requires a manual fsck
```

I launched the command

```
fsck -fy /dev/sda1
```

and the system has done operations on the filesystem but at the end of the procedure the system does not start but remains on the following screen:

```
/dev/sda1: THE FILE SYSTEM WAS MODIFIED

/dev/sda1: 603235/6373376 (0.2% not contiguous), ...

....

Pass 1: Checking inodes, blocks and sizes

...

Pass 5: Checking group summary information

(initramfs)
```

How can I start the system?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Boot drops to a (initramfs) prompts/busybox](https://askubuntu.com/questions/137655/boot-drops-to-a-initramfs-prompts-busybox)

Comment: Did you run `fsck` while the partition was mounted?

Comment: go with `fsck -n /dev/sda1` to display the problem, so we can figure the problem out easily.