# Error message on boot

Tags: boot, macbook

This message appears briefly on boot. My computer DOES boot after this but I'm wondering if there's anything I can do about it.

[image]

Comment: Check for an updated BIOS. Use `sudo dmidecode -s bios-version` to get your current version. Then go to the manufacturer's web site to check for an update.

Comment: This is closely related but there are similar questions elsewhere too: https://askubuntu.com/questions/1093882/unable-to-boot-after-installation-acpi-errors