# Is there a fix to those "hick-ups" in Ubuntu 20.04.1 LTS?

Tags: nvidia, 20.04, bluetooth, crash, amd-processor

I built myself a new Computer a few days ago. I saw this as an opportunity to completely switch to Ubuntu. I used a fresh install of 20.04 LTS and adjusted my drivers to eliminate screen tearing. Updated and installed my usual programs (Steam, discord, etc.).

Now, just over a week later, I have recognized several "hick-ups" as I would describe it. Sometimes my system lags extremely when I close Firefox. Also, when the PC wakes up, sometimes Bluetooth does not work and even `service bluetooth restart` does not work, so I have to reboot here, too. Then, after rebooting, my input source is switched from my microphone to my webcam. When starting the PC in the evening, nightmode does not work properly, so I have to turn it off and on again.
I really like Ubuntu and I do not want to back to Windows, but it's just these smaller issues that are absolutely disturbing. Is anyone here experiencing the same or knows how to fix these?

Here are my specs if it helps anyone:

- CPU: AMD Ryzen 5 3600
- GPU: Gigabyte GeForce GTX 1650 OC (lp)
- Mainboard: Gigabyte Aorus pro WIFI ITX
- RAM: Corsair Vengeance DDR4-3200 LPX
- SSD: Samsung 970 Evo 500GB

Comment: waking up has always had problems with bluetooth, fortunately there are solutions published. for the microphone, I think pavucontrol might be a solution. these same approach, issue by issue should be followed for the other problems.

Comment: Ubuntu won't be as smooth out-of-the-box as Windows, but most little quirks can be resolved if you stick with it.
+1 to `pavucontrol`, I use it with the `pasystray` GUI to much satisfaction. As to the general instability, try various video drivers. I'm currently having success with `nvidia-driver-440`.

Comment: This [answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/1261877/1139889) probably fix your issue for sure