# How to updat to latest BIOS when .exe is the only provider option - Ideapad 5-15ITL05 Laptop - Type 82FG

Tags: lenovo, bios, ideapad

How do I update my BIOS from an Ubuntu for my machine (Ideapad 5-15ITL05 Laptop - Type 82FG)?
checking the manufacture website:

https://pcsupport.lenovo.com/il/en/products/laptops-and-netbooks/5-series/ideapad-5-15itl05/82fg/82fg009riv/pf2js18r

There is a new bios version. They only have a .exe file.
I have wine, and am afraid running an exe from wine that updates a bios, if that makes any sense.
I contacted the support so they might send me a file i can slap on a usb and boot, but Lenovos response was "We do not support Linux OS. please contact Linux for support." (get it?)

[image: Updating bios]

Comment: There are several possible methods documented here: https://help.ubuntu.com/community/BIOSUpdate#Vendor_independent_updating_methods although some of the information may be out of date now regarding what evaluation/repair installations of Windows are available. FreeDOS might work but I think it will depend on the actual .exe file. Also see https://askubuntu.com/questions/1261876/how-to-update-the-computer-bios-firmware-without-using-windows

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to Flash BIOS with UEFI Tool on a (FAT32) usb stick as in :
https://support.lenovo.com/us/en/solutions/ht118103-flash-bios-with-uefi-tool-ideacentre-stick-300
(I didn't know it 2" ago, so that's why I'm writing it down somewhere ..)