# Not able to install Ubuntu 20.04 alongside Windows 10 pro dual boot

Tags: xubuntu, lubuntu, live-usb, usb-installation, amd-processor

I am trying to install Ubuntu 20.04 in my HP laptop alongside windows 10 pro. But I am not able to install.

- **Model**: HP ENVY Notebook - 15-ah151sa
- **Processor**: AMD A10-8700P Radeon R6
- **Operating system**: Windows 10 Pro
- **Bootable device**: USB
- **Tool used**: Rufus (Tried almost all options in this tool)

Screen stuck at:
[Screen where my laptop stuck during installation attached](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QnR7N.jpg)

Any guidance appreciated. Let me know if any steps I need to perform.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [My computer boots to a black screen, what options do I have to fix it?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/162075/my-computer-boots-to-a-black-screen-what-options-do-i-have-to-fix-it)

Comment: Have you updated UEFI from HP? And if SSD, updated SSD firmware? Did you create UEFI bootable flash drive from Rufus. It creates either only UEFI or only BIOS/Legacy. You must use UEFI. https://askubuntu.com/questions/1278772/unable-to-access-ubuntu-from-uefi &  https://help.ubuntu.com/community/UEFI
Shows Windows screens
https://askubuntu.com/questions/221835/installing-ubuntu-on-a-pre-installed-windows-10-with-uefi

Comment: I have tried using Legacy mode with nomodeset on. I am able to land on ubuntu desktop using try ubuntu option. But when I try to install, I am not having the option to install along side windows. Since my windows is running in UEFI mode, I think I am not seeing that option. So I have to drop that option @Pilot6

Comment: @olfred When I am trying with GPT in Rufus, my screen stuck at [Error image with EFI only](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LmCah.jpg). Not sure if I miss something.

Comment: Any help appreciated

Answer (score 0):

i have an 15-ah150na model with the same a10-8700p and have tried a few times to no avail. Recent talk of win11 and discovering that it would not be available to me thought i'd better get it working as a backstop in case support ceases for win 10. After many trials and reboots i have a method that worked for me. As the laptop now belongs to the Mrs my install is to an external usb3 disk (a safer option than certain death if anything went wrong). Anyhow here goes:-

1 update to latest bios in my case F.22
2 Set legacy support to enabled in the bios.
3 Boot a live stick of ubuntu 18.04.6LTS with noacpi nomodeset (this will hopefully boot the live cd properly so that you be able to make sure everything works ok)
4 Install as you wish (in my case to the external drive with the grub install to the same external disk)
5 Restart when finished as required.
Note if your bios is like mine f9 at startup will bring up a boot menu which has an option to boot from the external disk as the 4th or 5th option.
6 After restart i then updated and then upgraded up to 20.04lts using the software updater.

i now finally have a system that will boot 20.04lts so i'm happy i even installed xubuntu desktop and that works too.

i have tried many different configurations of options and this is the only one that would work so i'm afraid that's the only information i can offer. It worked for me but obviouslyi can't guarantee it will work for you but i think there's a good chance it might. Of course I would advise you back up your data before doing anything and everything you do is at your own risk.

Hope that helps and it works for you because i know what it's like banging your head against a brick wall with this stuff.