# Having Issues with Ubuntu Installation on Lenovo Ideapad 5i Pro

Tags: boot, system-installation, uefi, bios

I bought the laptop a few days ago without an operating system. Since then I tried to install Ubuntu and was challenged with several errors. I used 'Rufus' to create UEFI and BIOS/UEFI bootable USB, and every time I selected Ubuntu to be installed, the computer showed the following errors, in the corresponding order:

1. [After GRUB appears I see ACPI BIOS ERROR messages before Ubuntu 20.04 starts normally. How do I solve the problem?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1258641/after-grub-appears-i-see-acpi-bios-error-messages-before-ubuntu-20-04-starts-nor)
2. [nouveau "unknown chipset" On Installer](https://askubuntu.com/questions/598417/nouveau-unknown-chipset-on-installer)
3. [Error when installing: "unable to find a medium containing a live file system"](https://askubuntu.com/questions/15425/error-when-installing-unable-to-find-a-medium-containing-a-live-file-system)

When I press <kbd>F2</kbd>, I see the Lenovo panel, and that the Secure Boot is disabled and the mode is UEFI.

Comment: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=RAoJIdMJInw 
have you watched the vid?

Comment: Which version of Ubuntu are you trying to install?

Comment: @Adnan The newest LTS

Comment: @robgrune I know how to install Ubuntu. The challenge is the errors I get and therefore can't install it.

Comment: The newest LTS is 20.04 (April 2020). Your hardware is much newer. Conclusion: Use 21.10 that can be upgrade to the *next* LTS 22.04 in April next year.

Comment: Hi Adnan. In my experience, many pads, tablets, phones, even laptops require proprietary firmware and will not be compatible for any Linux distro. I tried to help a user with his Lenovo Thinkpad wifi, to no avail. So seems Lenovo is now in the non-compatible category. Thanks for posting your difficulties.