# My Ubuntu won't boot after I installed kde

Tags: boot-repair

My computer with ubuntu won't boot after I installed KDE and used it and now when I try to boot it brings up a command line that says

BusyBox v1.27.2 (Ubuntu 1:1.27.2-2ubuntu3.2) built in shell (ash) Enter 'help' for a list of built-in commands.

(initramfs)

Tutorial I used to get KDE:https://m.youtube.com/watch?v=HdA8mOEhIa8&ebc=ANyPxKpqQI_6_9oayjEgbdfb9p5YenAHKKL7SckvK-MTU-nEeOt0Scr2pWzdPLno89FaUy3Pfz8rxksG0c2o1Hm4GaGqtrctdw

Comment: How did you installed KDE? If you followed some tutorial you can [edit] the question to post the link.

Comment: If you want the KDE desktop, use Kubuntu instead since it ships with KDE by default. You'll be far less likely to run into issues and DE conflicts.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Boot drops to a (initramfs) prompts/busybox](https://askubuntu.com/questions/137655/boot-drops-to-a-initramfs-prompts-busybox)