# GRUB into BusyBox

Tags: boot, dual-boot, grub2

Before completely reinstalling I'd like to try to get some help here;

I've updated Ubuntu yesterday. After the next restart my system booted into the GRUB command line (as described in many other threads, e.g. https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/474510/unwanted-grub-command-prompt-while-booting).

After following pretty much every guide I was able to execute the `boot` command after

```
linux /boot/<path-to-image>
initrd /<path-to-image>
boot
```

But this doesn't solve my problem and instead brings up the BusyBox (like [Boot drops to a (initramfs) prompts/busybox](https://askubuntu.com/questions/137655/boot-drops-to-a-initramfs-prompts-busybox)).

From there I'm not able to do anything; `fdisk` does nothing, `exit` or `reboot` causes kernel panic.

I've also tried to boot from USB stick and ran `fdisk` - but that didn't help at all.

Is there anything left I can do?

(I'm running Windows AND Ubuntu in the same system, on two different SSDs)

Comment: May be best to see details, use ppa version with your live installer (2nd option) or any working install,  not older Boot-Repair ISO:
Please copy & paste link to the Boot-info summary report ( do not post report), the auto fix sometimes can create more issues.
 https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Boot-Repair & 
https://sourceforge.net/p/boot-repair/home/Home/ Best not to run fixes until someone reviews report. You may need advanced options and total reinstall of grub & kernel to re-generate configuration.

Answer (score 1):

I didn't know about the `boot-repair` utility (http://ubuntuhandbook.org/index.php/2016/11/install-boot-repair-ppa-fix-boot-problems/).

Booted via USB, installed boot-repair which was capable of fixing my boot. Thanks, boot-repair utility!