# Ubunutu 16.04 stop booting with busybox error

Tags: boot, initramfs

I have Ubuntu 16.04 PC with some application running and connected to internet at remote location, and few days before internet goes offline and pc goes offline. And  when I reboot the PC goat following messages.

[image] .

As a solution I have checked the answer here

[Boot drops to a (initramfs) prompts/busybox](https://askubuntu.com/questions/137655/boot-drops-to-a-initramfs-prompts-busybox)

and run the command **exit** and goat following messages.

[image]

And then as another solution I run the command

```
sudo  fsck /dev/sda2
```

And it gives the output

[image]

And reboot the PC and still same error happening. What could be the issue.

Comment: You've tagged Lubuntu, Lubuntu 16.04 LTS being a flavor had 3 years of support and is thus EOL (*5 years applies to Ubuntu desktop/server & Kylin for 16.04*). I would check your drive health (using it's SMART) from a 'live' system, I'd then explore your / partition. file system table (`/etc/fstab`) etc.

Comment: lubuntu tag is by mistake, actually I have three server on same location and when the internet goes offline, the three have the same error when reboot. And not sure if there power interruption happens.