# install problem ubuntu 16.04

Tags: system-installation

I'm using a USB to install ubuntu 16.04 and when I tell it to install a screen comes up that says "BusyBox v1.22.1 (Ubuntu 1:1.22.0-15ubuntu1) built-in shell (ash) Enter 'help' for a list of built-in commands
(initramfs)"  I tried testing ubuntu without installing, but it does the same thing. 
what should I do?

My previous question about version twelve was a mistake. sorry about the confusion

Comment: As you were answered in the comments of your [previous question](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1216965/ubuntu-install-error-on-windows-xp) : ubuntu 12 is end of life for years now, and therefore not supported anymore. Not questions are answered here regarding eol versions except upgrading to a supported one.

Comment: What should you do?   Answer = Install a supported release of Ubuntu.

Comment: @guiverc Busybox 1.22 is the actual version in 16.04... 12.04 would be 1.18 I believe.

Comment: Welcome to AskUbuntu, probably this would help. https://askubuntu.com/questions/137655/boot-drops-to-a-initramfs-prompts-busybox