# Ubuntu 18.04 crash

Tags: sound, alsa, login-screen, uuid

I have problem with Ubuntu 18.04 which is currently I am stuck at this screen. Does that mean I should reinstall Ubuntu or there is something I can do to fix the problem? If not how can I get out of this screen?

[image]

This happened after the sound broke and I tried some way in terminal to fix it, but nothing is working anymore.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Boot drops to a (initramfs) prompts/busybox](https://askubuntu.com/questions/137655/boot-drops-to-a-initramfs-prompts-busybox)

Comment: Hi, thanks for the suggested solution but I can't type anything in this screen. Any idea?

Comment: It can't find your boot disk. Is it seen in your BIOS? Can you please show me more of what you see on the screen. Your image is cut off, and may be missing some important detail. Do you have a Ubuntu Live DVD/USB available?

Comment: If you cannot type anything, then you would seem to have THREE perhaps inter-related problems: The duplicate, your sound, and keyboard-not-responding. Since you have not told us what you did to fix sound, we can only guess that you really, really broke your system badly. Gauging your skill level from the data you have provided, I would recommend backing up your data  and then reinstalling Ubuntu.