# I get Busybox built-in shell (initramfs) on every boot - help!

Tags: boot, 20.04, fsck, busybox

I recently did a clean install of Ubuntu 20.04 on my Dell Inspiron 5559 (only a couple of years old and in good condition). It has been working well for few days, but the last couple of mornings I've had major issues.

Yesterday it came up with

> Busybox built in shell (ash) and UNEXPECTED INCONSISTENCY : RUN fsck manually.

I googled solutions - no expert - and ran `fsck /dev/sda2`.
Seemed to fix the problem.

Happened again this morning - though now, it just says enter 'help' for a list of commands.  So I googled again, and did the same.  And a third time now.

My machine also seems to be struggling - it won't open any Libre Office documents, even those I was using earlier today.

I'm attempting to back everything up to my external hard drive and it keeps saying that folders & files have invalid filenames.

I'm very very worried I will lose everything - and don't have any technical knowledge.

[![Red cross on root folder][1]][1]

In the earlier `fsck` I ran, I saw this error message:

> Buffer I/O error on dev sda2, logical block 69730304, async page read
>   Error reading block 69730304 (Input/output error) while reading inode and block bitmaps.

I hit yes, after googling that step.

Then, in tonight's `fsck`:

> /dev/sda2 contains a file system with errors, check forced.

...and later:

> Block bitmap differences:...

No idea what any of this means.
Getting desperate.
Please advise.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Boot drops to a (initramfs) prompts/busybox](https://askubuntu.com/questions/137655/boot-drops-to-a-initramfs-prompts-busybox)

Answer (score 1):

This is a bug related to [this](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/linux/+bug/1835660). One easy way to solve this is to select LVM or ZFS partition while installing Ubuntu 20.04+.