# Can't boot anymore with Ubuntu Mate

Tags: boot, command-line, mate

I am new to the Ubuntu community and have a big problem: I cannot boot anymore after I made a terminal command.

I don't know what happened, but suddenly all the files in my `Downloads` folder got locked (with the lock icon) and I couldn't delete them anymore.

So I wrote a terminal command I found to unlock the folders (which I forgot) to set the permissions on my `Home` folder (which removed the lock icon after execution), but I still couldn't delete them.

When I rebooted, Ubuntu Mate did not reboot. I got errors messages like:

```
Error communicating to TPM chip ACPI BIOS error AE_AML PACKAGE LIMIT
```

The BusyBox (`initramfs`) is waiting for a manual command, but I don't know what to do.

I would really appreciate support, if you know what's going on and why Ubuntu doesn't boot anymore.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

"*suddenly all the files in my Download folder got locked*" suggests filesystem corruption or a faulty/dying hard drive.

- First, try to use [the `fsck` command to repair your filesystem](https://askubuntu.com/a/924547/19626)
- If your filesystem can be repaired, then backing up your data to some other media is wise, in case the problem re-occurs.
- If your filesystem can be repaired, but the problem re-occurs after another few boots, then run [a SMART test on your storage device (HDD/SSD)](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Smartmontools)

Comment: Thank you for your answer 535733. Unfortunately it seems like fsck command is not recognized (it is not part of the commands when I write <<help>>. I have tried sda1, sdax, sda5 and it didn't work: <<NOT FOUND>>. But if I write EXIT, I have some info: dev/sda5 contains a file system with errors, check forced. Inode 1310783 could be narrower. IGNORED. Inodes that were part of a corrupted orphan linked list found. dev/sda5: UNEXPECTED INCONSISTENCY: Run fsck manually (without -a or -p options) fsck exited with a status code 4. The root filesystem on dev/sda5 requires a manual fsck.

Comment: Is there any way to run fsck from a CD or USB...I have Linux Kodachi on a USB, could I run fsck from it...When I check that partition from Kodachi, it says it is unmounted.

Comment: UPDATE: THE PROBLEM HAS BEEN SOLVED AND UBUNTU IS NOW FULLY FUNCTIONAL. Here's how: 1) In initramfs I typed ''exit'' which gave me the corrupted partition (sda5 in my case). 2) ''fsck'' command was not recognised by initramfs, I booted from a USB Kodachi version I had. From Kodachi, I used gparted (which is already installed in Kodachi), selected my sda5 corrupted partition and repaired it with gparted repair function. Voilà! Be careful with the ''fsck'' command, as it could damage your root partition while it is mounted, and you won't be able to boot after. Thanks 535733 for your help.