# How to repair this?

Tags: boot, filesystem, ssd, 23.04, sgx

[I did nothing but reboot and it showed up. I tried to find the SGX option in the BIOS but there was nothing there, and I tried changing the SATA settings but that didn't work either. Now it is set to #### without RAID](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ejJMx.jpg)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Boot drops to a (initramfs) prompts/busybox](https://askubuntu.com/questions/137655/boot-drops-to-a-initramfs-prompts-busybox)