# Ubuntu not starting, initramfs error

Tags: boot, initramfs

I am having the following error on my ubuntu

```
    Gave up waiting for root file system device. Common problems:

-Boot args (cat /proc/cmdline) - Check rootdelay=(did the system wait long enough?) -Missing modules (cat /proc/modules; ls /dev) ALERT! UUID=22f93100-9860-44b7-8086-51b4404d499d does not exist. Dropping to a shell

BusyBox v1.27 2 (Ubuntu 1:1.27.2-2ubuntu3) built in shell (ash) Enter 'help' for a list of built-in commands.

(initramfs)
```

It started to happen after updating some drivers of it
I can enter the system using another version, I wanted to correct this one that is giving error
Any step-by-step tips?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Boot drops to a (initramfs) prompts/busybox](https://askubuntu.com/questions/137655/boot-drops-to-a-initramfs-prompts-busybox)