# initramfs prompt appears while booting - Error regarding zfs mountpoint

Tags: initramfs, zfs, 23.04

Hello i have a little problem with my pc i have **ubuntu** system **23.04**, last night everything was fine , i turned on my pc today there is initramfs prompt appears and when i type "`exit`"  command it  display this

```
(initramfs) exit
Gave up waiting for root file system device. Common problems:
- ﻿Boot args (cat /proc/emdline)
 - ﻿Check rootdelay= (did the system wait long enough?)
- ﻿﻿Missing modules (cat /proc/modules: Is /dev)
ALERT! ZFS=rpool/ROOT/ubuntu_sk17cr does not exist. Dropping to a shell!
BusyBox v1.35.0 (Ubuntu 1:1.35.0-4ubuntu1) built-in shell (ash)
Enter "help"  for a list of built-in commands.
```

can you help me solve this problem thank you i am ready to provide all the information to solve these problems.
Thanks

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Boot drops to a (initramfs) prompts/busybox](https://askubuntu.com/questions/137655/boot-drops-to-a-initramfs-prompts-busybox)