# how do I fix an Ubuntu based install that seems borked (no desktop)

Tags: boot, encryption, vmware

I have a VM on VMZWare of Kodachi which is based (iirc) on Ubuntu.
The host machine crashed and rebooted while the guest was running but not undertaking any 'work'. It's LUKS encrypted but I have the passphrase.

If I boot the vhd as a standard machine it asks for the key and seems too accept it. but then instead of going to the desktop it loads into 'busy box'

I can also attach the vhd to another VM. I used Ubuntu 22.x it shows up as two volumes. one ~750MB the other is the encrypted volume, but it just spins when I enter the passphrase.

I understand I should be using FSCK on it as a non-root, unmounted file system but am unsure how to proceed from here.

Plenty of PC experience from back to the DR/MS-DOS days but my *nix skills/knowledge are a little lacking.

can anyone help? happy to screen share if that is the only way.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Boot drops to a (initramfs) prompts/busybox](https://askubuntu.com/questions/137655/boot-drops-to-a-initramfs-prompts-busybox)